# Can the virtual machines created by Docker be used in a standalone way without Docker?

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

[Docker can creat virtual machines to be used as nodes in swarms](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create).

Can the virtual machines created by Docker be used in a standalone way without Docker,  or are they only usable by Docker?

For example, can a virtual machine created by Docker with VirtualBox driver be used just like a virtual machine created directly by VirtualBox, or can it be used only by Docker?

Thanks.

Comment: You miss-understand. Docker does not create virtual-machines. It creates containers. Containers have no kernel, they rely on features of the host kernel (namespaces, cgroups). All docker does is provide a nice interface to make these features easily usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important to note that *docker-machine* is different to docker engine.  Docker-machine is a way of managing hosts to run the docker engine.

Normally when people say "docker" they normally mean the docker engine.  Keeping the terminology consistent will help in understanding the documentation and in avoiding confusion.  *Docker* doesn't create VMs, but docker-machine can.

Now, when you use docker-machine to talk to a hypervisor or IaaS (eg AWS) infrastructure, it will create a VM on that Hypervisor.  The base OS will depend on the target platform and options.  You can see the options here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/os-base/.  After that docker-machine installs the docker runtime, so it can now be used to run containers.

The resulting image is a normal VM for the platform you target.